# How do I convert an old Nuxt 2 Express route redirect to Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

In a Nuxt 2 project I had a route handler like this:

```js
import express from "express"
const app = express()
// Install middleware
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const axiosConfig = {
  baseURL: config.url.backend,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}

// -- Routes --

app.get("/activate-account", (req, res, next) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/user/activate", req.query, axiosConfig)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return res.redirect("/users/change-password/?gid=" + response.data.gid)
      } else {
        throw new Error("Error activating account")
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      return res.redirect("/users/activation-failed?code=" + error.response.status)
    })
})
```

I am trying to use the new Nuxt 3 server/api folder to handle this, so I would have a file server/api/activate-account like:

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const {data} = await useFetch(`${config.url.backend}/api/user/activate`)
  if(data.value.status === 200) {
    //Somehow redirect to change password page
  } else {
    //redirect to failed page
})
```

I don't know what I can use to redirect the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sendRedirect, as mentioned in the docs (https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server) under "Sending Redirect"

So, e.g.:

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const {data} = await useFetch(`${config.url.backend}/api/user/activate`)
  if(data.value.status === 200) {
    return sendRedirect(event, "/users/change-password", 302)
  } else {
    return sendRedirect(event, "/users/activation-failed", 302)
})
```